# Can Google Docs auto-correct capitalization?

Tags: google-docs, formatting

In Microsoft Word, you can [change capitalization in a document](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-capitalization-or-case-of-text-1d86cf80-fbef-4380-8d6f-59a6b77db749) using the **Change Case** button. It includes options for **Sentence case**, **lowercase**, **UPPERCASE**, **Capitalize Each Word**, and **tOGGLE cASE**.

Does Google Docs have anything similar for auto-correcting capitalization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Change Case](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/change-case/ahpcjlihommmjokggmgpinfpflphlall) addon for Google Docs should do the trick.

> **Make changes to the case of text in block selections: uppercase, lowercase, first letter capitals, invert, sentence and title case.**
>
> Current features:
>
> - All characters to uppercase
> - All characters to lowercase
> - First letter capitals
> - Invert the case of each character
> - Sentence case capitalization
> - Title case capitalization
>
> [image]